# Flask.Too many values to unpack

Tags: python, flask

``Hi!I don't understand why this error pops up who can help me

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template
import sqlite3

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/main')
def index():
    with sqlite3.connect('/home/vlad/Рабочий стол/jobs_aggregator_Flask/data/data.db') as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT name_vacan,name_company,description,link FROM all_pars_data")
        name_vacan, name_company, description, link = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('base.html', name_vacan=name_vacan, name_company=name_company,
                           description=description, link=link, )
```

Comment: Welcome, can you please edit your post to include the error you're seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to store each column in its own variable, you can transpose the result of the `fetchall` call (which returns rows rather than columns as explained by John Gordon) using `zip`. I think that this is your intention:

```
name_vacan, name_company, description, link = zip(*cur.fetchall())
```

Each of these four variables now contains a tuple of length n, where n is the number of rows returned by your query.

Answer (score 1):

`fetchall()` returns a list of database row objects.  You're assigning these rows to four different variables via tuple assignment, but `fetchall()` returned more than four rows, so you got the error.

But even if four rows were returned, this code would still be wrong, because you're apparently expecting *columns* to be returned, not *rows*.